# How to preserve axis aspect ratio with tight_layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, aspect-ratio

I have a plot with both a colorbar and a legend. I want to place the legend outside of the plot to the right of the colorbar. To accomplish this, I use bbox_to_anchor argument,  but this causes the legend to get cut off:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

_, ax = plt.subplots()

extent = np.r_[0, 1, 0, 1]
space = np.linspace(0, 1)
probs = np.array([[norm.cdf(x + y) for x in space] for y in space])
colormap = ax.imshow(probs, aspect="auto", origin="lower", extent=extent, alpha=0.5)
colorbar = plt.colorbar(colormap, ax=ax)
colorbar.set_label(f"Probability")
ax.scatter(
    [0.2, 0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 0.6, 0.4], color="r", label="Labeled Points",
)
plt.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 0.5))
plt.title
plt.show()
```

#### Plot with legend cut off

[image: Plot with legend cut off]

To fix the legend, I insert a call to plt.tight_layout() before plt.show(), but this causes the aspect ratio to get distorted:

#### Plot with distorted aspect ratio

[image: Plot with distorted aspect ratio]

How can I show the entire legend and preserve the aspect ratio of the axes?

Comment: In this case, do you want to make the figure wider or the axes smaller?

Comment: (you could also move the legend to the top of the figure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage the ratio between axis height and width with [**`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html). Since you want them to be equal:

```
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

Then you can use [**`matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html) to fit the legend within the figure.
If you want to adjust margins too, you can use [**`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

_, ax = plt.subplots()

extent = np.r_[0, 1, 0, 1]
space = np.linspace(0, 1)
probs = np.array([[norm.cdf(x + y) for x in space] for y in space])
colormap = ax.imshow(probs, aspect="auto", origin="lower", extent=extent, alpha=0.5)
colorbar = plt.colorbar(colormap, ax=ax)
colorbar.set_label(f"Probability")
ax.scatter([0.2, 0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 0.6, 0.4], color="r", label="Labeled Points",)
plt.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 0.5))

ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it introduces another problem: Now the colorbar is taller than the axes.

Comment: Try to pass `bottom = 0.2` and `top = 0.8` parameters to `subplots_adjust`: `plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.1, bottom = 0.2, top = 0.8)`. You may need to adjust those parameters to optimize the result